# Missing Webstorm features in Sublime Text with plugin for JavaScript development

Tags: javascript, macos, ide, sublimetext, webstorm

I started with JavaScript and was looking for IDE with features like code completion, error checking, etc.

I tried Sublime Text editor with several plugins:

[ESLint](https://github.com/roadhump/SublimeLinter-eslint) + [JSHint](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-jshint) for error checking

[JavaScript Completions](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JavaScript%20Completions) + [TernJs](http://emmet.io/blog/sublime-tern/) for code completions

[FileHeader](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FileHeader) + [DocBlockr](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/DocBlockr) for documentation

[JsFormat](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JsFormat) for code formatting and [FixMyJS](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FixMyJS) for basic corrections

Now I can use Sublime editor for JavaScript development with fundamental IDE features. Recently I found WebStorm IDE but I didn't find any features which I miss in Sublime Editor. I use OS X (Yosemite) and while I scrolling source code in WebStorm, IDE is lagging.

I would like to ask WebStorm users which functions in this IDE are missing in sublime + plugins and which are better. I would also like to ask WebStorm users on OS X if IDE is lagging while scrolling source code.

Comment: JavaScript debugging, for example?

Comment: to avoid lagging when scrolling, please make sure you are not using version with bundled JDK 1.8 - it's known for performance issues related to editor redrawing.

Comment: You could read some of the posts on this thread in [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9224461), some of them talk about the differences between the two.

Comment: @lena I use debugger in Goggle Chrome and I tried debugger in WebStorm, which seems very similar. It's cool you can debug in WebStorm coffeescript or typescript, but does WebStorm debugger have more features than Chrome debugger for pure javascript?

Comment: @lena thank you, I tried version without JDK 1.8, but apparently JetBrains products have some problem with OS X Yosemite, because IDE is not lagging now but flickers while scrolling and it is really annoying.

Comment: it's a known issue (one of the reasons for creating a custom JDK - see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-131632#comment=27-872765, for example). It's not actually a problem of JetBrains products, it's a problem of Oracle JDK + OS X Yosemite

Comment: @saadq I found there _"I use webstorm for both Angular and Node because the integrated debugger doesn't require a context switch when debugging code"_  what is good point and WebStorm debugger is good for JavaScript "derivations" such as coffeescript or typescript and JavaScript frameworks..

Comment: @lena Thanks. I will follow this bug and try WebStorm again when it disappears :)

Comment: WebStorm has also features like source code refactoring and hints for fix errors. I think Sublime doesn't have any packages for these features.

Comment: I found another interesting feature. WebStorm supports Google Closure JSDoc Annotations with code completions and error checking features, I am not sure if Sublime or Atom editors have plugins for this.

Comment: File watchers is another nice feauture if you use build system in more projects.